# Display Image from bean

Tags: image, jsp

I have a bean with access to a image as byte[] here in the getImage method i convert a awt image to the byte array

```
public byte[] getImage() {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] imageInByte = null;
    try {
        ImageIO.write( (BufferedImage)image, "jpg", baos );
        baos.flush();
        imageInByte = baos.toByteArray();
        baos.close();
        return imageInByte;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return imageInByte;
}
```

I need to display the image with jsp within a table

like:

```
<table>
<c:forEach items="${beans}" var="bean">
    <tr>
    <td>${bean.name}</td>
    <td>${bean.origin}</td>
    <td>${bean.year}</td>
    <td>${bean.number}</td>
    <td>${bean.image}</td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Has it something to do with content type?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display an image which is in bytes to jsp page using html tags?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/943729/how-to-display-an-image-which-is-in-bytes-to-jsp-page-using-html-tags)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a img tag in your jsp file with src point to a servlet which will return the image byte array as a jpg image. You have to set correct mime type for the servlet output stream. One problem with this approach is that you have to save your image array in session for the servlet to pick it up.

Comment: it helped for my problem ... but now in my foreach the servlet call is done only once looking for solving this

Comment: @FordPrefect: do you mean you can only return one image? How did you call the servlet? In your foreach loop, you can set a request parameter to the servlet call with different ids for the images you want to return and in your servlet send back different images accordingly.

Comment: @FordPrefect: something like this <img src="image_servlet?id=1234"/> in your for each loop.