# Display byte array in gsp

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I want to loop through this class and display in a table. what is the easiest way to display the image?

```
class Crop {
    static hasMany = [diseases: Disease]
    int id
    String commonName
    String scientificName
    byte[] image
}

static mapping = {
    table: 'Crops'
    commonName length : 100
    scientificName length: 100
    image sqlType: "longblob"
}
```

Comment: Normally you would do an extra request for each image which are handled by a controller. Do you really have to do this inside gsp? And maybe you should accept some of your earlier questions first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the same thing as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/943751/639753).

Or you can create controller which provide image data stream from your entity. On GSP you could write:

```
<img src="${request.contextPath}/imageController/actionName?id=${entity.id}" ...
```

But this is unusual - storing images in entities as `byte[]`. You should consider changing it to `String` which would indicate a path/filename of the image.

Comment: I wouldn't say storing images in the DB is unusual, I've seen it used on numerous occasions, and to be honest is usual a good first choice for a lot of applications.

Answer (score 2):

You can if you don't mind the lack of browser compatablity use `data:` uri encoding:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,${crop.image.encodeBase64()}"/>
```

see the Wikipedia page on [Data URI encoding scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#Format)

@Xeon suggest the more conventional approach, ie create a controller that returns an image response with the correct mime type and the byte array as the body.