# display the image from database

Tags: html, mysql, jsp

I have created a program in JSP to fetch the image and display it on web page. Program is working correctly image is displayed but other contents are not displaying. Below is the code

```
<% 
        byte[] imgData = null ;
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/buysell","root","root");
         Statement stmt = con.createStatement();       
 ResultSet resultset =stmt.executeQuery("select * from imagemain where id=1;") ; 
  while(resultset.next())  
  {
      Blob bl = resultset.getBlob(2);
byte[] pict = bl.getBytes(1,(int)bl.length());
response.setContentType("image/jpg");
OutputStream o = response.getOutputStream();
%>
<img src="<%o.write(pict);%>" width="10" height="10">
<h1>Vishal</h1>
<%
out.print("1");
o.flush();
o.close();
  } 
        %>
```

the program is not displaying the `<h1>Vishal</h1>`. Please assist on this

Comment: Debug? does the query work -> run it in the database client (MySQL admin, SQLYOG or phpmyadmin) to see . is the while loop running?   resultset maybe NULL??

Comment: Thanks Raymond for your response... Image is displayed correctly but other HTML content like `<h1>Vishal</h1>` is not display correctly.

Comment: You are returning an image. To show text and image you need two http accesses or creat a data URI using B64 encoding. In both cases you need to start with text/html

Comment: Thanks mplungjan for your response... But I didn't get your point Can you please explain briefly.. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You need to read up on how standard http access works

For now try

```
response.setContentType("text/html");
OutputStream o = response.getOutputStream();
%><img src="data:image/jpg;base64,    <%o.write(Base64.encode(pict));%>" width="10" height="10">
   <h1>Vishal</h1>
```

More info here: [How to display an image which is in bytes to JSP page using HTML tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/943729/how-to-display-an-image-which-is-in-bytes-to-jsp-page-using-html-tags/943751#943751)

OR

```
<img src="otherjspreturningimage.jsp" />
```