# Displaying img in jsp from mysql

Tags: mysql, jsp

I am trying to insert image in mysql database & retrive it and displayimg it another jsp page but while retriving its not displaying image in browser instead it started download can you help me in this. . , and my code is . .,

Addimage.jsp.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org       /TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="AddImg.jsp" method="post">
Image<input type="file" name="file" value="upload" /><br>
<input type="submit" value="Add"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>`
```

and AddImg.jsp

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@page import="java.io.*" %>
<%
Connection con;
PreparedStatement stmt;
ResultSet rs;
byte[] b=null;
//int f;

%>
  <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
 pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
     <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org                 /TR/html4/loose.dtd">
     <%
  String filenm=request.getParameter("file");

String f="C:/visualverify02/limitedimages/"+filenm;
File file=new File(f);
FileInputStream fin =new FileInputStream(file);

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/imgdb","root","password");
stmt=con.prepareStatement("insert into img values(?)");
//String str="insert into img values ('"+file2+"')";
stmt.setBinaryStream(1,(InputStream) fin, (int) (file.length()));
int count=stmt.executeUpdate();
%>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
if(count>0)
{
out.println("img inserted");
rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM img ");
int i = 1;
if(rs.next()) {
    Blob len1 = rs.getBlob("imgfile");
    //int len = (int)len1.length();
     b = len1.getBytes(1,(int)len1.length());

    }else{out.println("Img not selected");}



    response.setContentType("image/jpg");
    OutputStream o=response.getOutputStream();

%>
<table>
<tr><td><%o.write(b); %></td></tr>
<%

o.flush();
o.close();

}


else{
out.println("Not inserted");
}
%>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all I think it's bad practice to have scriptlets in your jsp. I would suggest use at least a [http servlet](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html) as a controller that deals with storing the image.

Secondly, the way the code is written you are not writing an image to a html page, but to a file, that will trigger downloading that file. To do what you want to archive your contenttype should be "text/html" and the output should be a html with an image tag like described in [how to show byte data in an img tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/943729/how-to-display-an-image-which-is-in-bytes-to-jsp-page-using-html-tags)

Comment: Thanks for ur reply . . , is it k if i hav content type as "text/html" & here i hav outputstream insted of bytearrayoutputstream. Can u show me with an example .

Comment: I hav changed content type to text/html but it showing only 1 image , its not showing respective image wht i select in previous page . .