# Spring,Hibernate with mysql image is not displaying properly

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

Yesterday I have posted this question..But did not get any answer.

In my project I have stored image file in mysql database.
the table is like:

```
+-----------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| upload_id | int(11)             | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| uId       | int(20) unsigned    | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| file_name | varchar(128)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| file_data | longblob            | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Now I am fetching image data **my dao class** is:--

```
  public List<ImageClass> fetchallimage(int uId) {
           
            
            ImageClass imageClass= new ImageClass(uId);
    
            String hql = "FROM ImageClass WHERE  uId = :uId1 ";
            
            
            Query query =  (Query) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql).setParameter("uId1",  imageClass.getUserId());
            
            return query.list();
            
                    
        }
```

My ImageClass is:--

```
    @Table(name = "imageStore")
    public class ImageClass{ 
    private long id;
            private String fileName;
            private byte[] data;
    ---getters and settrs with @Column annotations----
      
}
```

My controller class is:-

```
   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String ImageFetch(Map<String, Object> map,HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpSession session,HttpServletResponse response) {
            
                    
                int uid= (int) session.getAttribute("uId");
                
                List<ImageClass> imageClass;
                
                imageClass= PicService.fetchallimage(uid);
                

                map.put("image",imageClass);
                return "account";
            }   
        }
```

and jsp page is:-

```
  <c:forEach items="${image}" var="info">
     <div style="width:380px;display:block;text-align:center;">
        <img src="${info.data}" 
        border="0" alt="Dating" style="margin:10px;padding:15px;border:10px solid #FEB4DE;background:#FECDE9;"></div>
      </c:forEach>
```

But the picture is displaying,like below:-

[image]

In page image looks like:  **[B@1284b24**

why??what I have to do to achieve the image??Please guys suggest me.

I have edited :--

```
for (ImageClass temp : imageClass) {
                
byte[] encodeBase64 = Base64.encode(temp.getData());
String base64Encoded = new String(encodeBase64, "UTF-8");
 map.put("image",base64Encoded); }
```

and in jsp :--<`img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,${image}" />`

still not getting picture.

in logger I am getting output:--

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display an image which is in bytes to JSP page using HTML tags?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/943729/how-to-display-an-image-which-is-in-bytes-to-jsp-page-using-html-tags)

Comment: May be..But How I have to do in my program??

Comment: I would 1/ read the duplicate answers, 2/ find a way to base64 the bytes (common-codec) 3/ expose some method in `ImageClass` to construct the data URI and 4/ call that method from the JSP

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert that imageTo String and then you can easily display in JSP. I presume its a byte[]. Use a @Transient variable, it will help :

```
import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;

        BASE64Encoder base64Encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
 object.setTransientString("data:image/png;base64," + base64Encoder.encode(object.getByteArrayDataVariable()));
```

In jsp, use the img tag and put the String variable there. Enjoy.

Comment: I have tried what you have said..But still not getting result.I have edited my question..What I have wdited..please check..

Comment: Use png, not jpeg in the String, it doesn't matter which type of image user uploaded, use png. If that doesn't work, I guess we have to substring your byte[], after converting it to String and again encoding it..